# Signed XML Check Signature is failing with hash Error

Tags: c#, cryptography, saml-2.0, signedxml

I am trying to check SAML Signed Response in Dot Net 4.8 MVC Project

My code is

```
_xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                _xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
                _xmlDoc.XmlResolver = null;
                _xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

        XmlNodeList nodeList = _xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//ds:Signature", _xmlNameSpaceManager);

                SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(_xmlDoc);
                
                if (nodeList.Count == 0) return false;

                signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

                X509Certificate2 serviceCertificate = null;
                foreach (KeyInfoClause clause in signedXml.KeyInfo)
                {
                    if (clause is KeyInfoX509Data)
                    {
                        if (((KeyInfoX509Data)clause).Certificates.Count > 0)
                        {
                            serviceCertificate = (X509Certificate2)((KeyInfoX509Data)clause).Certificates[0];
                        }
                    }
                }
return signedXml.CheckSignature(serviceCertificate, true);
```

Its getting false as signature validation

So I enabled logs and below is the error

```
[SignedXml#026c9e6f, VerifyReference] Reference Reference#000df9b5 hashed with 
"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" (SHA256Managed) has hash value 
348aa65d5b67edfae901cd4e2596065e75839a18c9a5d3a63d3fd85e48c232d8, expected hash value 
869e1b0273833271a23349cd9bc7bddb597c2277c323abddead0cfe798ae3f63.
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml Information: 12 : [SignedXml#026c9e6f, 
VerificationFailure] Verification failed checking references.
```

Please suggest

Comment: I suggest you provide the raw data as received from the partner on the wire (you can use a trace tool, like Chrome DevTools get the base64 encoded SAML response), and the data that you are doing the validation against (the raw data in `_xmlDoc`). My bet is that you aren't handling the canonicalization properly. My curiosity, however, is more around **WHY** you would build something like this, when there are a number of packages out there for DotNet that handle all of this for you... Is it for academic purposes? If not, just go find a good SAML package, like ITFoxTec, SustainSys, or Kentor...

Comment: Thanks @andrew , How can I handle canonicalization for sha 256 , please provide some code snippets if you have

Comment: Also for your curiosity answer i m not allowed to use third party dll as per requirement of the project as per it's domain

Comment: Xmldoc is just decoded base 64 saml response loaded